# How do I get file explorer to expand to a current folder in my documents in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shortcuts

"Expand to current folder" works great with some folders. But I have a bunch of folders I want to have expanded in one instance of file explorer while I'm working, so I've made shortcuts to them and pinned them to Quick Access. When they're certain folders in my documents, accessing them through a shortcut or Quick Access won't automatically expand to them.

I would like the folders to expand under This PC > Local Disk (C:) > Users > _kyle > Documents > ... and not Kyle Delaney > Documents > ... if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question and that this helpful. You say you created shortcuts and pinned them to Quick Access.
Have you tried going to the folder you want expanded, then right clicking on the folder and then selecting "Pin to Quick Access"? I did this with both the SendTo and Start folders for windows, so I could quickly access them. By right clicking on the Quick Access folders needed, then selecting, Open in new Window, several Explorer windows can be opened fairly quickly. I also, do this with some other folders I regularly use in Quick Access.

Comment: Well like you said, I've already pinned them to Quick Access. And I like to have just one instance of File Explorer open so multiple instances don't clog up the taskbar and overlap each other and so I can move files between folders more easily when File Explorer is maximized.